# PHP - Delete object from AWS S3 with REST API

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to delete object from amazon s3 with REST API.
I create a curl command but I get 403 error: "SignatureDoesNotMatchThe request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided".

I used in AWS documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectDELETE.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html

This is my code:

```
$host = 's3.amazonaws.com';
$url = "https://" . $bucket . '.' . $host . '/' . $file;
$date_full = date('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T');
$date = date('Ymd');
$longDate = gmdate('Ymd\THis\Z');
$shortDate = gmdate('Ymd');
$credential = $accessKeyId . '/' . $shortDate . '/' . $region . '/s3/aws4_request';
$hashed_payload = strtolower(hash("sha256", ""));

$headers = [
    'X-Amz-Algorithm' => 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
    'X-Amz-Credential' => $credential,
    'X-Amz-Date' => $longDate,
    'X-Amz-Expires' => 86400,
    'X-Amz-SignedHeaders' => 'host',
    'x-amz-content-sha256' => $hashed_payload,
    'Host' => $bucket . '.' . $host,
];
ksort($headers);
$signed_headers_string = strtolower(implode(';', array_keys($headers)));

// Build canonical request
$canonical_request = "DELETE\n"; // HTTPRequestMethod
$canonical_request .= '/' . urlencode("http://s3.amazonaws.com/" . $bucket . "/" . $file) . "\n"; // CanonicalURI
$canonical_request .= "\n"; // CanonicalQueryString

foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
    $canonical_request .= strtolower($header) . ':' . trim($value) . "\n"; //CanonicalHeaders
}

$canonical_request .= $signed_headers_string . "\n"; // SignedHeaders
$canonical_request .= $hashed_payload; // HashedPayload

// Build string to sign
$string_to_sign = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n";
$string_to_sign .= $date_full . "\n";
$string_to_sign .= $date . '/' . $region. "/s3/aws4_request\n";
$string_to_sign .= hash('sha256', $canonical_request);

// Calculate signature
$signature_date = hash_hmac('sha256', $date, 'AWS4' . $secretKey, true);
$signature_region = hash_hmac('sha256', $region, $signature_date, true);
$signature_service = hash_hmac('sha256', 's3', $signature_region, true);
$signature_request = hash_hmac('sha256', 'aws4_request', $signature_service, true);

// Build Signature
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $string_to_sign, $signature_request);

// Calculate final Authorization header
$headers['Authorization'] = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=' . $credential . ', ';
$headers['Authorization'] .= 'SignedHeaders=' . $signed_headers_string . ', ';
$headers['Authorization'] .= 'Signature=' . $signature;

// Convert headers to key:value strings
$curl_headers = array();

foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
    $curl_headers[] = "{$header}:{$value}";
}

// Init curl
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curl_headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");

$result = curl_exec($curl);
```

Someone can help me please to understand what is the problem?

Comment: Your hashing an empty string? 
`$hashed_payload = strtolower(hash("sha256", ""));` 

(http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php)

Comment: @MisterSmith, yes I didn't have payload. That is what AWS wrote about it: HashedPayload is the hexadecimal value of the SHA256 hash of the request payload.

Hex(SHA256Hash(<payload>)
If there is no payload in the request, you compute a hash of the empty string as follows:

Hex(SHA256Hash(""))
The hash returns the following value:

e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855  
For example, when you upload an object by using a PUT request, you provide object data in the body. When you retrieve an object by using a GET request, you compute the empty string hash.

Comment: I was getting the same error try to delete using Elasticsearch. In my case I was not encoding the canonical URI correctly. This may not fix your problem, but you should be using `rawurlencode()` (instead of `urlencode()`) as it is RFC 3986 compliant. Also see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting keys that have upper and lower case letters.  Use all lower case letters in the keys before calling `ksort()`.

You are also including headers that don't need to be included.  The documentation you referred to only asks for `x-amz-date`, `x-amz-content-sha256`, and `host`.  Use only those headers.

```
$headers = [
    'x-amz-date' => $longDate,
    'x-amz-content-sha256' => $hashed_payload,
    'host' => $bucket . '.' . $host,
];
ksort($headers);
```

Your canonical request should have an extra line break after adding the headers:

```
foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
    $canonical_request .= strtolower($header) . ':' . trim($value) . "\n"; //CanonicalHeaders
}
$canonical_request .= "\n";
```

I'm not sure if this change is necessary, but in $string_to_sign, I use the date format provided by $longDate, not $date_full:

```
// Build string to sign
$string_to_sign = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n";
$string_to_sign .= $longDate . "\n";
$string_to_sign .= $date . '/' . $region. "/s3/aws4_request\n";
$string_to_sign .= hash('sha256', $canonical_request);
```

You are setting `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` twice, first to `PUT` and then to `DELETE`.  The last setting is likely the one being used, but I would remove `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');` for the sake of clarity.